# Passing macro arguments to macro function

Tags: c, function, macros, arguments, parameter-passing

How do I pass macro arguments along with another integer variable to a macro function?

```
#define SUM(X, Y, Z) X + Y + Z
#define FOO 1, 2

void print(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Sum: %d", a + b);
}

int main(void) 
{
    // Normal function works as expected
    print(FOO);

    // Macro function not working
    int a = 3;
    printf("\nMacro Sum: %d", SUM(FOO, a));

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Sum: 3
Macro Sum: 6
```

However, I get the following error:

```
main.c:18:41: error: macro "SUM" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
     printf("\nMacro Sum: %d", SUM(FOO, a));
```

Comment: When you expand that line using `SUM(FOO, a)`, `FOO` is not expanded until after the arguments have been determined.  There are only 2 arguments, but the macro expects 3 — hence the message.  The expansion of `FOO` into `1, 2` would happen next.

Answer (score 5):

Macro arguments are not expanded when the macro call is parsed. After the macro call is parsed, each use of a macro parameter in the macro definition text is replaced with the macro-expanded argument, except for macro parameters used with the `#` or `##` operations (stringify and token paste), which are replaced with the unexpanded text of the macro argument. Then the `#` and `##` operations are performed, and then the entire macro body is scanned one more time.

The consequence is that `SUM(FOO, a)` is parsed aa having two arguments. Since the macro requires three, thatvwon't compile.

You can work around this, to some extent, by using one extra level of macro expansion:

```
#define CALL(macro, ...)  macro(__VA_ARGS__)

printf("\nMacro Sum: %d", CALL(SUM, FOO, a));
```

Now the use of the `__VA_ARGS__` parameter (which happens to be a varargs parameter, although that makes absolutely no difference to the expansion order) will be expanded before the replacement text is rescanned, so `FOO` will be invoked with three arguments.

---

By the way, outputting a newline character at the beginning of an output line is a bad habit which will get you into trouble someday. Output lines should have a newline at the end of the line:

```
printf("Macro Sum: %d\n", CALL(SUM, FOO, a));
```

There is nothing wrong with *also* writing a blank line beforehand by putting a newline at the beginning as well, but regardless, you should almost always terminate outpur lines with the `\n`. Otherwise:

1. The line might not be written immediately. Line-buffered output is not actually sent to the output device/file until a newline is sent.
2. If the program is a console app and it terminates without properly closing `stdout`, you will find yourself typing the next shell command at rhe end if the last output line. This tends to confuse line-editing input libraries like `readline`.

Answer (score 0):

Single macro argument would work:

```
#define SUM(X, Y, Z) X + Y + Z
#define FOO1 (1) 
#define FOO2 (2)

void print(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Sum: %d", a + b);
}

int main(void) 
{
    // Normal function works as expected
    print(FOO1,FOO2);  

    int a = 3;
    printf("\nMacro Sum: %d", SUM(FOO1, FOO2, a));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sum: 3
Macro Sum: 6
```